# SAS replace variable with the variable's value before sending to remote server

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I'm new to SAS and I'm trying to retrieve data from a remote server.

Below is the code that I am trying to execute on the remote server:

```
rsubmit;
libname abc'server/sasdata'; *This is where the datasets are located;   
data all2009;
    set abc.file_2007:; 
    by index date time;
    where index in (var1) and time between '8:30:00't and '12:00:00't;
run;
endrsubmit;
```

Currently, I am trying to pass along the variable `var1` which contains the string `index` that the "query" needs.  `var1` is evaluated on my local machine and contains the value `'abc'`.

But, since `var1` is evaluated locally, trying to refer to the variable on the remote server produces an error since `var1` does not exist there.

If I run the code as follows (with the explicit value of `'abc'`) it runs fine:

```
...
set abc.file_2007:; 
by index date time;
where index in ('abc') and time between '8:30:00't and '12:00:00't;
...
```

I need to run this "query" dynamically.  Is there a way to force `var1` to be replaced by its actual value (ie. `'abc'`) before trying to execute the code enclosed in `rsubmit` and `endrsubmit`?

---

**UPDATED:**
Entire Code (I left out the remote server specific ones, but I'm able to connect no problem):

```
LIBNAME local 'C:\...\Pulled Data\New\';
FILENAME csvfile 'C:\...\Pulled Data\New\indexes.txt';

%macro getthedata(nrows,ystart,yend); *nrows is the number of rows in the text file;

    %GLOBAL var1 var2 var3 var4;

    %do i=1 %to &nrows;
        %do m=&ystart %to &yend;

            DATA local.trow; 
               INFILE csvfile FIRSTOBS=&i OBS=&i;
               INPUT var1 $ var2 $ var3 $ var4 $;
            RUN;

            PROC PRINT DATA = local.trow;
            TITLE "Title - &i. &var1. &m";
            var var1 var2 var3 var4;
            RUN;

            proc export data=local.trow
                outfile="C:\...\Pulled Data\New\Indices_&i._&m..csv"
                dbms=csv replace;
            run;

            signon username=_prompt_;
            %syslput VAR1 = &var1;
            rsubmit;
                    libname abc'server/sasdata';    
                    data all2009;
                         set abc.file_2007:; 
                         by index date time;
                         where index in (&VAR1) and time between '8:30:00't and '12:00:00't;
                    run;
            endrsubmit;

        %end;
    %end;
%mend getthedata;

Options MPRINT;

%getthedata(1,2007,2007)
```

With this code, the `PROC PRINT` statement correctly prints a table showing the `var` variables and their values.  The `TITLE` statement properly evaluates the `i` and `m` variables, but leaves the `var1` off altogether.

The `proc export` statement creates the correct CSV file containing the expected values for each `var` variable.

As suggested, I tried to declare the `var` variables as GLOBAL, but that didn't seem to have any effect.  The code still appears unable to properly pass the `var1` variable to the remote server.

Again, the code works perfectly well if I replace `&VAR1` with the actual string value of the variable.

The error I get is:

```
ERROR: Syntax error while parsing WHERE clause.
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a quoted string,
              a numeric constant, a datetime constant, a missing value.
```

Could it be that the `WHERE` clause in this case cannot accept variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you put the VAR1 value in a macro variable, on/in your local machine/session you can pass that macro to the remote server using the %SYSLPUT command.

you place it between the SIGNON and RSUBMIT commands.

```
Signon;
%SYSLPUT VAR1=&var1;
RSubmit;
```

Then &VAR1 is available in your remote session. Depending on what you are passing in &VAR1, you may need some macro quoting. Post the value if you have problem with this method.

Comment: Thank you for your post.  I have actually tried this solution before, but couldn't get it to work. When I try to run it, I get `WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference VAR1 not resolved.` in the Log and the query fails.  The local `VAR1` itself is created within a macro.  I'm not sure what I'm missing here... (The actual value of `var1` is `'XXE'`).

Comment: Some additional info: `var1` is a char variable that is imported from a CSV file.  I just noticed that I am able to output this variable via `PROC PRINT` and `PROC EXPORT` but can't get it to resolve (for example) in the `TITLE` of the `PROC PRINT` statement--it shows up as "test - &var1".  I'm not sure what's going on with this.

Comment: Sounds to me that your local variable in the macro isn't properly scoped.  There is no such thing as 'char variable' in macroland, so don't worry about that - every macro variable is text.  You may need it to be a global variable, if you're creating it in a macro but then need it passed outside that macro.

Comment: Well, I don't see that you created &VAR1. That would explain why you are getting the warning. I use this method all the time, it definitely works.

Comment: I tried that, but it produced the same error (I have updated the code above to reflect this).  I also get the following: `ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a quoted string, a numeric constant, a datetime constant, a missing value.`

Comment: After more testing, the source of this problem does not appear to be passing the variable to the remote server... I will post a new question regarding the new issue (no room to explain here).  But in the end `%SYSLPUT` did work for passing.  Thank you so much for all of your help!